# Google sheet - IF formula is not working properly?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Image of the problem (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie0ZV.png)

The IF formula is supposed to give the answer yes if the two values are the same, which they are. Although I get the answer No. Why is this happening?

The two values are themselves formulas from other sheets.

Image of attempt to solve (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qetL3.png)

I tried to use numbers directly put in the same sheet (no numbers coming from a formula), and then it works. But I need to use values that are based on formulas taking numbers from other sheets.

Answer (score 0):

while the values derived from the formulas is just showcasing 2 decimal places, its likely that when you expand/increase the decimals to extreme end there could be a possible difference (alike the one you can see in the screenshot for reference; the EXACT() in Cell B3 throws 'FALSE')

You could ROUND() them up for exact match scenario.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem, one of them had X,0200 and the other one X,01999.